# How to properly rotate a Turret?

Tags: unity, rotation

I'm having problems understanding how to properly rotate a Turret. 
Using Unity Editor, I've simulate turret movement, so I take note that turret can move with this clamp factor (for instance):

( value expressed in euler angles )

X = 1-4

Y = 0-0

Z = 98-100

I've write this code but it not works properly:

```
float rotX = Random.Range (Cannon1MinX, Cannon1MaxX);           
float rotY = Random.Range (Cannon1MinY, Cannon1MaxY);
float rotZ = Random.Range (Cannon1MinZ, Cannon1MaxZ);

Cannon1.transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (rotX, rotY, rotZ),Space.World);
```

Every time I've to work with rotation i become mad :(

What is wrong ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Euler angles to rotate it might lead to [Gimbal Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock). To properly rotate your turret you will need to use [Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

---

If you simply need a turret to look on some object rotating all axis, you can use `transform.LookAt(Vector3 positionOfTheEnemy)`.

You can restrict this rotation too, for example, before calling previous method, you need to set the Y position to position of the object you are trying to rotate. Meaning that no rotation is required for some axis because "it is aligned with object you are trying to rotate"(actually it's not, but we make it think so).

```
Vector3 positionOfTheEnemy = enemy.transform.position; // Creates a new object type of Vector3 because it's struct, so it has no reference to enemy position
positionOfTheEnemy.y = turretTransform.position.y;
turretTransform.LookAt(positionOfTheEnemy);
```

---

If you need some kind of specific rotation you can use:

`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, valueBetween0And1);` [Quaternion.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html)

`transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, valueBetween0And1);` [Quaternion.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html)

---

If you need to rotate it by euler angles - you can use `Quaternion.Euler()`.

And many other methods and things that quaternions can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you see in the example: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

```
// Rotate the object around its local X axis at 1 degree per second
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime);
```

Move one axes at a time and see how the value are moving for your need, example:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * x);                // for X+ axis
transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * y);                   // for Y+ axis
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * z);              // for Z+ axis
```

Then you can tweak them accordingly.

Note: Try a constant value and generate random values one axis at a time, otherwise it wont make sense as the turret moves.